# ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing : Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am new in SQL . When I am going to use this query , it occurs error . Here is my query :

```
with new_table ( loan, customer_city ) as 
(
 select l.loan_number , c.customer_name, customer_city 
   from loan l
   join borrower b on b.loan_number = l.loan_number 
   join customer c on c.customer_name = b.customer_name
  order by loan_number 
)
select customer_city 
  from new_table;
```

Comment: You can see the great importance of stating your Oracle version.... remember to do this every time you ask a question, and encourage everybody to do the same! +1 for that.

Answer (score 6):

Column aliasing in the declaration of a CTE was introduced in Oracle 11.2. In 10g, you must create the aliases within the subquery itself, something like

```
with new_table as (select loan.loan_number as loan,    .....)
```